# ios alternate content fallback in IE 8 & 9 (flash won't show)

Tags: ios, html, flash, internet-explorer

I'm trying to keep our flash for our desktop visitors but made an animated gif solution for ipad users.  I have this code below, the gif works great on ipad, and everything works great in Chrome, FFox and Safari, the flash shows as usual -- but realized today that in IE 8 & 9 -- the flash doesn't show anymore.

I would like to know if there is any additional code I can add - to work in IE -- OR, is there another bit of code I can add that will at least add a static image to IE.  Obviously, I **prefer to have the flash showing in IE** again if anyone knows the solution.  I thank you much in advance.

```
 <!-- test of alternate image -->
    <div id="altimage" style="display:none">
<img src="http://www.kqimageserver.com/kqimages/flash/1ST.gif">
</div>

<div id="aleosoftflash" style="display:block">

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"     codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"     width="540" height="140">
<param name="movie" value="flashmovie.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed src="https://www.kqimageserver.com/kqimages/flash/July27_2012.swf"
quality="high"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
WMODE="transparent"
width="510"
height="300"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) !=   null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null)) { document.getElementById("altimage").style.display = "block"; document.getElementById("aleosoftflash").style.display = "none"; }
</script> 
<!-- end test  -->
```

Comment: Finally got the code formatted up there, thanks - if you can help me, I'd appreciate it.  Looking for some kind of code where the flash will still show on desktops in IE 8 & 9, and the animated gif will show on ipads.  Thank you so much in advance for anyone's help.